# UIAutomation get TableView cell name

Tags: javascript, ios, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I've written a simple script that goes through a menu in my app. I can access each cell but I'm not being able to retrieve their names.

Here is my log tree:
[image]

And those are the methods:

```
function goThroughAllSideMenuCells() {

    for (var index = 0; index < sideMenuCellsCount; index++) {
        var cellName = getNameForCellAtIndex(index);
        UIALogger.logMessage(cellName);
        if (cellName == "Check-in") {
            openCheckInCell();
        } else if (cellName == "Planta") {
            openPlantaCell();
        } else {
            openSideMenuItemWithIdentifier(cellName);
        }
    }
}

function getNameForCellAtIndex(index) {

    return sideMenu.cells()[index].name();
}
```

Comment: Hi @vyudi do you have the implementation code for this, you haven't define sideMenu or sideMenuCellsCount ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your get name function

```
function getNameForCellAtIndex(index) {

    return sideMenu.cells()[index].staticTexts()[0].name();
}
```

I've noticed a pattern since Xcode6 that changed something with cell names and now they are sometimes broken apart into multiple staticText elements so if your cell had a name like (item1), (item2) 
This may now show up in two unique staticText items. So you may want to edit the function to handle getting more than just the first static text(which is what I added to your function).